# Can I use db.Another_collection inside mapreduce?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, bigdata

I heard in a MongoDB conference that it is possible to use data from other collections inside mapreduce.

When I tried `db.collection.findOne(..)` it raised this error:

```
failed: exception: ReferenceError: db is not defined near...
```

Is the syntax wrong?

Comment: db object is not available anymore

Comment: So what is the alternative for making big calculations, updates and flagging on a sharded system? on the application side it is very slow to question the database. Should I think about using Hadoop mapreduce ?

Comment: Maybe but you might also be thinking about your scenario in a way that means you have to use a lot more computing power than you should

Answer (score 1):

It seems mongodb map reduce will only operate on the collections its invoked against. I think this was permitted before `v2.4`.

According to the [release log](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#additional-limitations-for-map-reduce-and-where-operations) of 2.4, this feature is removed.